# Tirar Scroll no navegador quando o menu estiver ativo

Tags: html

Boa tarde

Tenho um menu feito em html, css e um pouco de js. Ele está funcionando normalmente, porém, gostaria de "corrigir/adaptar" uma questão nele na versão mobile.

Coloquei ele para ocupar 100% de altura quando ele estiver aberto com o height: 100vh. Porém, dependendo do meu conteúdo (do body) ao dar o scroll o menu não ocupa 100% da tela e sim somente 100% da tela que estou vendo.

Para corrigir isso coloquei o menu com a position: fixed. E pronto resolver (não aparece mais o conteúdo do body e nem quebra a altura do menu), porém, o navegador cria uma barra de rolagem (por causa do conteúdo do body).

Como eu consigo desativar essa scroll do navegador somente quando o menu estiver ativo no mobile?

Estou colocando meu código.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Menu Mobile
  


  
    Logo
    
      Menu

Sobre

Produtos

Portfólio

Contato

Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, saepe. Enim totam aperiam ipsam magni at, cum natus. Libero doloribus necessitatibus ducimus ipsa debitis beatae minima voluptas voluptatibus tenetur sapiente.

const btnMobile = document.getElementById('btn-mobile');

function toggleMenu(event) {
if (event.type === 'touchstart') event.preventDefault();
const nav = document.getElementById('nav');
nav.classList.toggle('active');
const active = nav.classList.contains('active');
event.currentTarget.setAttribute('aria-expanded', active);
if (active) {
event.currentTarget.setAttribute('aria-label', 'Fechar Menu');
} else {
event.currentTarget.setAttribute('aria-label', 'Abrir Menu');
}
}

btnMobile.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
btnMobile.addEventListener('touchstart', toggleMenu);

function setTopo(){
$(window).scrollTop(0);
}
$(window).bind('scroll', setTopo);

body,
ul {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

a {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: sans-serif;
}

a:hover {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

#logo {
font-size: 1.5rem;
font-weight: bold;
}

#header {
box-sizing: border-box;
height: 70px;
padding: 1rem;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
background: #e7e7e7;
/*Adicionei ao original*/
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}

#menu {
display: flex;
list-style: none;
gap: 0.5rem;
}

#menu a {
display: block;
padding: 0.5rem;
}

#btn-mobile {
display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
#menu {
display: block;
/*position: absolute;*/
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 70px;
right: 0px;
background: #e7e7e7;
transition: 0.6s;
z-index: 1000;
height: 0px;
visibility: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
}
#nav.active #menu {
height: calc(100vh - 70px);
visibility: visible;
overflow-y: auto;
}
#menu a {
padding: 1rem 0;
margin: 0 1rem;
border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
#btn-mobile {
display: flex;
padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
font-size: 1rem;
border: none;
background: none;
cursor: pointer;
gap: 0.5rem;
}
#hamburger {
border-top: 2px solid;
width: 20px;
}
#hamburger::after,
#hamburger::before {
content: "";
display: block;
width: 20px;
height: 2px;
background: currentColor;
margin-top: 5px;
transition: 0.3s;
position: relative;
}
#nav.active #hamburger {
border-top-color: transparent;
}
#nav.active #hamburger::before {
transform: rotate(135deg);
}
#nav.active #hamburger::after {
transform: rotate(-135deg);
top: -7px;
}
}

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -3):

Dá sim porém acredito que talvez não seja a melhor forma de agir em relação ao menu, mas segue abaixo a solução.

Primeiro iremos separar o item do DOM ao qual queremos desabiliar a barra de rolagem:

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');
```

Para parar a rolagem:

```
body.style.overflow:'hidden';
body.style.height:'100%';
```

Para restaurar a rolagem:

```
body.style.overflow:'auto';
body.style.height:'auto';
```